# Getting jQuery to work with Netscape 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, conflict, netscape

Netscape fails to read a lot of jQuery written. What steps do you take to overcome these, and how much of the market do netscape users take up?

Comment: Do you have any data which indicates that your site audience uses Netscape 7 & 8? If not, don't bother with those two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps I would take:

1. Let it fail
2. Wait for Netscape users to notice they are using a long dead browser with security holes in it

The market share for Netscape is as close to zero as makes no matter.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, 0%?

Having said that, I have to admit that jquery fails on a lot of sites while prototype works, in my ancient Konqueror 3.5.10, so maybe there's a pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

Although I grew up on Netscape ;-) ...[**its no longer maintained (R.I.P)**](http://blog.netscape.com/2007/12/28/end-of-support-for-netscape-web-browsers/)

Thus as much as I'm all for the "support all browsers" mantra - supporting users of a now "dead" technology seems like a tall task.

IIRC, the [**jQuery support matrix**](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility) is based on supporting the latest supported major version of a major browser (and 1 level previous). ***Netscape 7 and 8 are both excluded from this list***.

I would suggest a simple "Please Upgrade" notice for the site... and since the users are on Netscape, Firefox would be a very compatible path to upgrade on since the concepts and layout are very similar (e.g. bookmarks, context menu options, etc.)

Thus providing a Download link for Firefox 3 would provide users a smooth guided path to upgrade.

Maybe just a simple iframe with **[this](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/upgrade.html)** would work well.